# JAVA : How to pick directory from the list of directory which has name containing Timestamp ( latest one)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have folder /tmp/builddatefolder/
This folder contains list of folders , Having Names

02-13-2025.20.38
02-13-2024.20.30
02-12-2023.20.20
02-11-2024.20.38

Question is how to pick folder having latest date in name

I have tried

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy.HH.mm");                                                                              
LocalDate latest = inputs.stream() 
  .map(s -> LocalDate.parse(s, f))                                          
  .max(LocalDate::compareTo) 
  .get();
System.out.println("LATEST FOLDER DATE ="+latest);
```

Output is 02-13-2025

**Expected Output 02-13-2025.20.38**

Can anyway please help me in getting good way of desired output ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to parse to [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), **not** `LocalDate`, you are losing the time information.

Then, since your required format is custom, you need to format the latest. It matches the input parse format, so you can reuse the existing formatter.

```
public class RandomStuff {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> folders = List.of("02-13-2025.20.38", "02-13-2024.20.30", "02-12-2023.20.20", "02-11-2024.20.38");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy.HH.mm");
    LocalDateTime latest = folders.stream()
            .map(folderName -> LocalDateTime.parse(folderName, formatter))
            .max(LocalDateTime::compareTo)
            .get();
    System.out.println("LATEST FOLDER DATE = " + formatter.format(latest));
  }
}
```

Note that calling [`Optional.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) without presence check will lead to `NoSuchElementException`, if the optional is empty. This may happen if the stream is empty. Consider handling this case.

Example of handling by providing default result:

```
String latest = folders.stream()
        .map(folderName -> LocalDateTime.parse(folderName, formatter))
        .max(LocalDateTime::compareTo)
        .map(formatter::format)
        .orElse("there were no folders");
System.out.println("LATEST FOLDER DATE = " + latest);
```

Answer (score 0):

The moment your code does `map(s -> LocalDate.parse(s, f))`, you have discarded the directory name;  it is no longer available.

The easiest solution is to remove the call to `map` entirely:

```
String latest = inputs.stream() 
  .max(Comparator.comparing(s -> LocalDateTime.parse(s, f)))
  .get();
```